# gke master upgrade when current version is 2 versions behind oldest available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a gke cluster running 1.12 as master and nodes versions. We were supposed to upgrade to 1.14 today but were not able to proceed since we can't go up 2 versions and 1.13 is not supported any more.

An important detail is that we had node pools still running 1.10, but these were upgraded to 1.12 just before the aborted master upgrade node upgrade to 1.14.

```
    validMasterVersions:
    - 1.15.11-gke.12
    - 1.15.11-gke.11
    - 1.15.11-gke.9
    - 1.15.11-gke.5
    - 1.15.11-gke.3
    - 1.15.9-gke.24
    - 1.14.10-gke.37
    - 1.14.10-gke.36
    - 1.14.10-gke.34
    - 1.14.10-gke.32
    - 1.14.10-gke.31
    - 1.14.10-gke.27
```

```
$ gcloud container clusters upgrade production --master --zone northamerica-northeast1-a --cluster-version 1.14.10-gke.37
Master of cluster [production] will be upgraded from version
[1.12.10-gke.22] to version [1.14.10-gke.37]. This operation is
long-running and will block other operations on the cluster (including
 delete) until it has run to completion.
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.upgrade) ResponseError: code=400, message=Master cannot be upgraded to "1.14.10-gke.37": cannot upgrade the master more than a minor version at a time.


$ gcloud container clusters upgrade production --master --zone northamerica-northeast1-a --cluster-version 1.13.12-gke.30
Master of cluster [production] will be upgraded from version
[1.12.10-gke.22] to version [1.13.12-gke.30]. This operation is
long-running and will block other operations on the cluster (including
 delete) until it has run to completion.
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.upgrade) ResponseError: code=400, message=Master version "1.13.12-gke.30" is unsupported.
```

How does one upgrade to a more recent version in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

big upset ! I’ve enabled auto upgrade on all node pools to see if it would trigger something and it did. My master have been upgraded to 1.13 in the next minutes so I could proceed to upgrade to the target version!

auto upgrade was not enabled because we have certain pods that are not able to handle it.